# Is it possible to create a parametrized css style?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have CSS style which draws a button. I need to reuse this style to draw a button of different color.

```
.button {
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   border: 1px solid orange;
   (...)
}
```

I know I can override CSS attributes. But the problem here is that I have to override almost all code of the button and it doesn't make sense. Its easier to create another CSS class which differs from this only by color values.
Is it possible to create some style which can take the colors as parameters, preserving all other css attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the runtime substitution of GWT ([Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Runtime_substitution)) with the annotation @eval

Runtime substitution:

> Provides runtime support for evaluating static methods when the
>   stylesheet is injected. Triggered / dynamic updates could be added in
>   the future if we allow programmatic manipulation of the style
>   elements. (cfr the doc)

For example:

```
@eval buttonColor com.myApp.MyTheme.getButtonColor();

.button {
   color: buttonColor ;
   background-color: black;
   border: 1px solid orange;
   (...)
}
```

The method used during the evaluation must be **static**

```
 public class MyTheme {

...

    public static String getButtonColor(){
       return "white";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, F.Geraerts! This really works, though I doubt I should follow this quite complicated way of solving my task. Hope GWT developers will invent something less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

GWT supports parameterized CSS at compile time. This enables you to embed compile-time directives in your CSS file, e.g.

```
@def TEXT_COLOR   #A0A0A0
```

Then you can use the value in CSS rules:

```
.some-class {
   color: TEXT_COLOR;

}
```

You also have access to the values from Java (at compile time). You can read about the feature here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource

Comment: Thanks fred, I used this before as a kind of a constant in CSS, but I cannot get how can I reuse my CSS class with this. You provided the way to reuse the constant, thats great, but I want reuse the class!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new class with your button class.

```
.newclass{
color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

Just make sure you have `!important` added to the new class color property.